# Introducing break and continue in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, break

Below part of code is copied from this snippet available at [django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/). This code may be working fine for given version but now i want to use it for latest version of django i.e 2.0 and with python-3. **Below part of code snippet is given the error :**

```
    return template.mark_safe(''.join(map(template.force_unicode,
AttributeError: module 'django.template' has no attribute 'mark_safe'
```

```
def render(self, context):
    return template.mark_safe(''.join(map(template.force_unicode,
                                          _render_nodelist_items(self,context))))
template.NodeList.render = render
```

if possible make it working for django 2.0 as i need to use it at multiple place in my project.

Comment: That code was written for Django 1.2 in 2010. I have a feeling you may have to change many other things to get it working with Django 2.0. Can you not do this within the view and leave it out of the template?

Comment: @Blender I've changed few lines of code which are mostly related to syntax. After that it pop up above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

def render(self, context):
  return mark_safe(
            ''.join(map(force_text(template.render()), _render_nodelist_items(self,context)))
         )
```

Comment: template has no attribute render. please at the code in the link. @Emmanuel Mtali